# Graphics/images tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

It's pretty unclear which tags people should be using for referring to graphics problems:

- graphics
- graphicx  (a package)
- images
- external-images
- diagrams
- drawing
- picture   (an environment)

Some consolidation would be good, I think. (`graphics` is also a package but I've never  seen it used.) Then we should create tag wikis so we can tell people which to use when.

I suggest keeping

- graphicx  (a package)
- picture   (an environment)

for obvious reasons, and then defining tags specifically for the following meanings:

- drawing packages, programmatic and GUI-based
- including external graphics such as eps/pdf/jpg/png/svg/etc.

I'd suggest just using the ‘graphics’ tag for both of these, actually, but if you wanted to split then up then maybe

- graphics-drawing
- graphics

respectively.

Answer (score 4):

I think that also "diagrams" might be worth keeping, but otherwise I totally agree. (Posted as an answer so that you can downvote.)

Comment: What's the difference between a "diagram" and a "graphic" in terms of a distinction that would make sense on the tagging level?

Comment: @Will: I'm not really sure about this myself (that's why the "might" in the answer). My feeling is that "graphic" is more about including images, and also function graphs, and that things with nodes are "diagrams". I'd always say "TikZ diagram".

Comment: But you can also draw a function graph in TikZ. So for your example, I'd tag with "graphics-drawing" and/or "tikz" in that case depending if the question was generic ("how can I draw a diagram like *this*?") or specific ("how can *tikz* draw...?").

Comment: @Will: I'm [well aware](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5400/1235) (and glad `:-)`) that TikZ can do graphs. Still, if I would ask a question about how to draw this and that _diagram_, then I'd probably find it natural to tag it with "diagrams". It's mostly a question of usage in the English language. Maybe [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagram) can help?

Comment: If diagrams is set as a synonym for graphics, then people can use (and search for) whichever tag they want.